# Making a Specific Program Use Nvidia Graphics Card

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, intel-graphics, minecraft

Ok, so I have searched far and wide for this. My computer is running Nvidia by default (so says all the tests I've tried, as well as Nvidia Settings). Despite this, Minecraft is still running on Intel graphics. I've blacklisted the intel card, no result. Does anyone know anything else? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Y520 laptop

Comment: You could set this up with Bumblebee, or at least you could a few years ago. I've tried for weeks to get it working and I have never been able to get it to work. I'm fairly sure the project is half dead or on life support. I'd be very interested to know if there's any other way.

Comment: I was under the impression that bumblebee was for using both graphics cards simultaneously. To me, at least, it seems that if minecraft is going to use a different card than the system default, then that won't help. Of course, I didn't get anywhere, so there are all the chances in the world that I'm wrong. I will try bumblebee later.

Comment: How do you even know if minecraft is using this or that video card?